# Is my flash drive dead?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

My flash drive did not eject correctly from a Linux machine, (Fedora 12, I think) and now I can't get any machine to recognize it. I've tried Windows and Linux machines. (I don't have access to a Mac) It doesn't make a sound when I put it in. It doesn't show up in My Computer or Disk Management. I'm not too familiar with Linux, but I look in a file viewer and disk manager, and didn't see it anywhere.

I was told there might be some special programs that might be able to see it, but I wasn't given names or anything. I'm thinking the drive is dead, but hoping its not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the answer for this question? http://superuser.com/questions/116701/dead-usb-flash-drive?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like my drive is dead. None of the solutions provided worked. I still get power to the drive but I've had zero luck getting anything to read or recognize it, even some tools mentioned in the link from ChrisForrence. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the windows machine with you you can check it whether is it getting detected in device manager and disk management if its there then its alive and just need the proper formatting. On your linux system Open terminal from the taskbar. Gain root privileges with the following command:type #su root
Create a new directory and mount the flash drive onto that directory with the following command: #mkdir /mnt/flashdrive

## mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/flashdrive

to check content type #ls /mnt/flashdrive

try and check whether its working or not?

Comment: if you want to test whether its alive or not then you can plug your flash drive to any of the USB port of your PC and select the first boot device as USB DRIVE or FLSH drive and then try to start it is it displays a cursor blinking on top left corner showing indication that its trying to boot than it might be alive or working else its completely dead